# Parent link need to go first child submenu

Tags: menus, links, walker

I use this walker for menu in `functions.php`

```
class main_menu_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
        global $wp_query;
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        $class_names = $value = '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
        $class_names = ' class="'. esc_attr( $class_names ) . ' nav-item"';

        $output .= $indent . '<li id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '"' . $value . $class_names .'>';

        $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

        $item_output = $args->before;
        if ( $args->walker->has_children && 0 === $depth ) {
            $item_output .= '<span class="nav-link">';
        } else {
            $item_output .= '<a class="nav-link" ' . $attributes . '>';
        }

        $item_output .= $args->link_before .apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );
        $item_output .= ( $args->walker->has_children && 0 === $depth ) ? ' </span>' : '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;
        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}
```

Get [this structure menu](https://jsfiddle.net/51qszpLu/):

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav nav__top-menu">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <span class="nav-link">About</span>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">text 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">text 2</a>
            </li>   
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

If parent item have submenu - is becoming `span`

How to make - click on parent item and go to first child ?

**Update**

I found this [plugin](https://gist.github.com/leoken/4395160). Its search child page which has posted first `function has_published_children`. In my menu position of pages may be changes. Need function to search pages not by date published, but by position in menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19113582/wordpress-click-on-parentpage-redirect-on-first-child-page-programmaticaly)

Create template for parent pages:

```
<?php
    /*
        Template Name: Redirect To First Child
    */
    if ( have_posts() ) {
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post();
            $pagekids = get_pages( "child_of=" . $post->ID . "&sort_column=menu_order" );
            $firstchild = $pagekids[0];
            wp_redirect( get_permalink( $firstchild->ID ) );
        }
    }
?>
```